# Finding mean and standard deviation across image channels PyTorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, mean, standard-deviation

Say I have a batch of images in the form of tensors with dimensions (B x C x W x H) where B is the batch size, C is the number of channels in the image, and W and H are the width and height of the image respectively. I'm looking to use the `transforms.Normalize()` function to normalize my images with respect to the mean and standard deviation of the dataset *across the C image channels*, meaning that I want a resulting tensor in the form 1 x C. Is there a straightforward way to do this?

I tried `torch.view(C, -1).mean(1)` and `torch.view(C, -1).std(1)` but I get the error:

```
view size is not compatible with input tensor's size and stride (at least one dimension spans across two contiguous subspaces). Use .reshape(...) instead.
```

**Edit**

After looking into how `view()` works in PyTorch, I know realize why my approach doesn't work; however, I still can't figure out how to get the per-channel mean and standard deviation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just need to rearrange batch tensor in a right way: from `[B, C, W, H]` to `[B, C, W * H]` by:

```py
batch = batch.view(batch.size(0), batch.size(1), -1)
```

Here is complete usage example on random data:

**Code:**

```py
import torch
from torch.utils.data import TensorDataset, DataLoader

data = torch.randn(64, 3, 28, 28)
labels = torch.zeros(64, 1)
dataset = TensorDataset(data, labels)
loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=8)

nimages = 0
mean = 0.
std = 0.
for batch, _ in loader:
    # Rearrange batch to be the shape of [B, C, W * H]
    batch = batch.view(batch.size(0), batch.size(1), -1)
    # Update total number of images
    nimages += batch.size(0)
    # Compute mean and std here
    mean += batch.mean(2).sum(0) 
    std += batch.std(2).sum(0)

# Final step
mean /= nimages
std /= nimages

print(mean)
print(std)
```

**Output:**

```py
tensor([-0.0029, -0.0022, -0.0036])
tensor([0.9942, 0.9939, 0.9923])
```

Comment: The reason this is not right is because you have averaged out by number of images in fact it should be averaged out across the pixels.

Answer (score 13):

Note that variances add, not standard deviations. See detailed explanation here: https://apcentral.collegeboard.org/courses/ap-statistics/classroom-resources/why-variances-add-and-why-it-matters

Here is the modified code:

```
nimages = 0
mean = 0.0
var = 0.0
for i_batch, batch_target in enumerate(trainloader):
    batch = batch_target[0]
    # Rearrange batch to be the shape of [B, C, W * H]
    batch = batch.view(batch.size(0), batch.size(1), -1)
    # Update total number of images
    nimages += batch.size(0)
    # Compute mean and std here
    mean += batch.mean(2).sum(0) 
    var += batch.var(2).sum(0)

mean /= nimages
var /= nimages
std = torch.sqrt(var)

print(mean)
print(std)
```